# Error installing winshell (python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1)

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install winshell under Python 3.3.0 / Windows 7.
(I should say that I have only a fuzzy notion of how package installing works, so my apologies if I'm making a basic blunder ... this stuff clearly is not really aimed at mere mortals).
What I did was: I opened a CMD window & navigated to the Python33 directory.  I typed

```
pip install winshell
```

and got "...*downloading winshell 0.6 zip* followed by *running setup.py egg_info for package winshell*...
and then I got
*python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1*  (in the log file)

I've tried googling generally and in here - most of the posts are moderately incomprehensible - to me at least.  There are tentative suggestions in comments to an answer that suggest I'd need to install either pwin32 or win32con.  And that pwin32 can't be installed with pip.  But I haven't found a definitive 'how to' for installing winshell.

Before I go down either of those rabbit holes, is it correct that, in order to install & use winshell, do I need those modules?  And please point me to the best, simple, instructions for doing that.

...

This is all for the purpose of getting the target path of a shortcut as in:

```
path = winshell.shortcut(filethatisashortcut).path
```

so as to kludge os.walk to follow shortcuts (Windows, remember!).   If there's a more direct method - please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the pywin32 module according to the [docs](https://winshell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#prerequisites-compatibility):

> Prerequisites & Compatibility
>
> The module has been tested on versions of Python from 2.4 to 3.2. It may 
>   also work on older (or newer) versions. You’ll need Python 2.5+ for context 
>   manager support. It’s tested with the most recent pywin32 extensions, but 
>   the functionality it uses from those libraries has been in place for many 
>   versions.

(Also looking at the [modules imported in the source files](https://github.com/tjguk/winshell/blob/master/winshell.py), you clearly need to install **Python for Windows extensions** (`pywin32`). Don't have access to a windows machine to test, but why don't you go by the book first.)

Comment: Ok so I need pywin32 but not win32con?  ive started downloading pywin3... unfortunately i was a bit slow to spot that the download is one of those nasty things that dumps extra garbage on my system so now ive got to backtrack & remove all extraneous c**p.   Life is never easy.
Once Ive installed pywin32, i just goback and retry the pip install winshell?  Or is there something else Ill need to do?

Comment: `win32con` should be included with your [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) install. Shouldn't hurt to `pip uninstall` and reinstall  `winshell` following `pywin32`.

Comment: Ok so I installed pywin32 apparently successfully.
I then did the pip uninstall winshell (got 'not installed' response)
then re-did pip install winshell, and got the same egg_info error 1 result.
What do I try next?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Did you make sure to install py2in32 for the right Python version and architecture?

Comment: Here's what I tried: 
I did a clean install of Python3.4.3 on a WinXP VM. Then I `pip install`ed winshell without issues ("Successfully installed winshell-0.6..."). Importing `winshell` fails at this point (ImportError: No module named 'win32con'). I next installed PyWin32 from the latest build. Following this step, importing `win32com` or `winshell` works. I'm using the vanilla Python from python.org. Please edit your question by posting the full traceback.

Comment: I downloaded the Python3.3 64 bit which is what I have.   (I also have 2.7 installed for other projects but dont want / need winshell) for that.  Installing pywin32 didnt ask me anything about versions or where to install.
Just to be clear, I ran  pywin32-218.win-amd64-py3.3.exe from the download folder and it just ran; then went to Python33 folder for the pip uninstall winshell & pip install winshell.   Is there some way to verify if pywin3e2 installed Ok?

Comment: By default, `pywin32` should install into something like `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages`. Can you post the output of `import win32com` ?

Comment: win32com imports Ok,  winshell doesnt.  my test prog has import win32com and import os, winshell ast 1st 2 lines.  this is the result:
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/MyScripts/Audio/shortcut2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import os, winshell
ImportError: No module named 'winshell'

Comment: Here's something else to try before long: upgrade `setuptools` using `pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `easy_install -U setuptools`. Then do `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall winshell`

Comment: Ok, well, step 1 gave 'no such option --upgrade', so i tried step 2 which gave a windows pop up 'might not have installed successfully' (how helpful!), step 3 gave 'no such option --force-reinstall'

Comment: Your packaging tool (`setuptools`) might be broken. To separate `pip`/`easy_install` from `winshell` issues, try putting two files [`winshell.py` and `__winshell_version__.py`](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/winshell/winshell-0.6.zip#md5=378164955ff8511eaebc64fda8a04d77) -- both found inside the archive on PyPI or github -- directly into your site-packages directory (find it using `import site; site.getsitepackages()`).  We're trying to obviate the packaging tool here. I put them under `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages`. Then reopen the shell and try to `import winshell`.

Comment: Well, 1 step forward and 1 back.  Doing what you said (actually I put them inside a winshell directory under site-packages) I can import successfully.
So I have now moved on to two more problems in that two different sample codes for accessing short cut target paths dont work.  I will try to go back to the respective authors to verify whats going on.  
Bottom line for this thread ... winshell seems to be successfully installed  now.   And I guess I have to figure out how to repair setuptools.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88836/discussion-between-rflack-and-maksim-yegorov).